# Silverlight and linq/ria select how to, do the following

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria

```
query_TMEditSheet = _
                    From tm In Context_DomainService1TMTM.GetTMTMSQuery()
                    From ts In Context_DomainService1TMTM.GetGECODsQuery()
                    Where tm.tmsDate = MainPage.TimeSheetDateSelect_selectdate.Date
                    Where tm.tmsUserID = ts.codType
```

> Defination method select many is not accessible in this context

**want to select tmtms records whose userid is present in the codType(of the gecod table)**

please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want to do is:

```
from tm in Context_DomainService1TMTM.GetTMTMSQuery()
join ts in Context_DomainService1TMTM.GetGECODsQuery() on tm.tmsUserID equals ts.codType
where tm.tmsDate = MainPage.TimeSheetDateSelect_selectdate.Date
```